# Lecturer wants us to give an object a print() method instead of overloading toString()

Tags: java, overloading

When it comes to overloading console output, there seems to be a general consensus that you should overload toString(), not print().

However, my lecturer wants me to create an object that has a print() method, with the goal of printing a special output tailored to that object.

So, my question is, is this correct? Is it done? Should I just give the object an overloaded toString() method instead?

Here's the code he wants us to work around:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
DVD dvd = new DVD(genre, title);
dvd.doSomething();
dvd.print();
}
```

Comment: Maybe he wants the print method to internally call the toString method?

Comment: Hi, so I would write an overloaded toString() method, and call it from print()?

Comment: "So, my question is, is this correct?" It's not illegal so I assume it is correct. "Is it done?" I don't know, have you done your homework?

Comment: The real problem here is that we were given almost no background info, he wants us to learn ourselves... So I want to make sure I learn this properly, and this seems like reinventing the wheel when I could just overload toString()

Comment: "Hi, so I would write an overloaded toString() method, and call it from print()?" Nope, your lecturer seems to want a distinction between "toString()" and "print()" - it is a valid request.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi No, that sounds *exactly* like what the lecturer might want--`toString` *returns* a string but doesn't *print* anything.

Comment: To the downvoters generally: This isn't a spectacular question, but it's reasonable, the OP seems to have done some research, and it's answerable rather clearly.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I guess I'll try and get familiar with the print() method and how I could use it for this purpose, thank you !

Comment: "this seems like reinventing the wheel" - well, apprentices need to learn how to shape a wheel don't they?

Comment: Thank chrylis, I know it's probably an annoying question for a lot of people, but I feel like this really has to be clarified, especially if there are people out there in positions of power who teach others to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My lecturer wants me to create an object that has a `print()` method, with the goal of printing a special output tailored to that object.

If that is the assignment, then that is what you should do.

As for `print()` vs `toString()`, they may have different purposes. To illustrate, assume you have a `Person` class with `name`, `phone`, and multiple address fields (`street1`, `street2`, `city`, `state`, and `zipcode`).

`toString()` should return a short descriptive string that helps identify the object. It will often be used when debugging, where a `List<Person>` will show the objects in a comma-separated list, e.g.

```
[John Doe, Jane Smith]
```

If the `toString()` method returns too much information, the `List.toString()` output will become useless for debugging.

`print()` is specifically for printing the object by itself, so it may want to print on multiple lines, e.g.

```
Name:    John Doe
Phone:   123-555-1212
Address: 123 Main St.
         Apt. 5
         Pleasantville, NY 10570
```

You do not want `toString()` to return a multi-line string like that.

Comment: Ahh, that's a very good insight. I hadn't considered the nuances of how the Strings themselves should look. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The `toString()` method is intended to *return* a `String` representation of the object; in your case it might return a string that looks something like `Comedy - Titanic (1997)`. It sounds like what your instructor wants you to do in the `print()` method is to send that output to the console--so something like `System.out.println(this)`.

On a more general note, good for you for learning about best practices and for asking questions. However, keep in mind that in my experiences many (or even most) instructors aren't familiar with best practices, and in a case like this you should (1) clarify it with your instructor and then (2) write it in the suboptimal way just for your assignment if the instructor is insistent on having it that way.

Comment: Thank you very much , I'll see if I can work off this.In my experience, lecturers are either gone batty with correcting so many student's messy code or totally complacent about it,

Comment: @Alex I think the big lesson for you to learn here is that computers are *absolutely* precise about instructions. Even though `toString` is used for printing objects out to the console, there's nothing *in the method itself* or its API that has anything to do with the console. The distinction is picky, but learning good software design involves learning to distinguish specific areas of responsibility between components (formatting a string here, printing strings to the console there).

Answer (score 0):

I think your instructor actually wants you to learn the best practices, even tho in this example this is a bad idea. Imagine if a DVD was something else and you couldn't just `System.out.println` it. He's teaching you this way, because it would be difficult and not efficient to let's say print picture of a DVD on the screen, just to test. This is my opinion, but teachers have some techniques and I think this is one of them. Just imagine the print method is just a `stub` for now and you will have to implement more advanced functionality later (like printing picture of the DVD on the screen) and printing it to the console is satisfying at this moment, just so the interfaces know that method exists and functionality is not important at this stage.

Comment: This could be the case, I'm going to try and do it his way, it can't hurt I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't wrong. What if the next next exercise is to call another function inside the print()?
The Object.toString() documentation says:

> Returns a string representation of the object.

It's not wrong to use the output of this method to show to your end users but mostly it's used for internal debugging purposes. You definitely would not want call another method from the toString method.
The toString() method must be stupid simple.

What if you want to add a call to another function like this:

```
public void print() {
    System.out.println(getLabel());
    sendToThePrinter()
}
```

You see the problem? If you would put this inside your toString() method afterwards, you will get into trouble.

Comment: Thats a good point, going to try it this way now, I'll be back if something goes horribly wrong haha